# Почему некоторые шаблоны (Live Templates) не синхронизируются в PHPStorm?

Tags: phpstorm

При синхронизации настроек с удалённым репозиторием:

```
File -> Settings Repository...
```

я обнаружил, что у меня стали пропадать мои шаблоны:

```
Settings -> Editor -> Live Templates
```

или не до конца синхронизироваться: на удалённом — старая версия, а локально — новая.

---

**Что может на это влиять?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.** В именах групп шаблонов (`Template group...`) и самих аббревиатурах не используйте специфические символы; такие как амперсанд (`&`), плюс (`+`), прямой слэш (`/`), круглые скобки (`()`) и другие; так как в этом случае на удалённом репозитории они будут заменены на нижнее подчёркивание (`_`) и будут возникать конфликты.

В именах групп шаблонов исправно работают:

- цифры (`0-9`);
- буквы английского алфавита (`a-zA-Z`);
- пробелы;
- дефисы (`-`).

В именах аббревиатур:

- цифры (`0-9`);
- буквы английского алфавита (`a-zA-Z`);
- дефисы (`-`).

**2.** Попробуйте отключить автосинхронизацию:

```
Settings -> Tools -> Settings Repository... -> Auto Sync
```

и синхронизировать настройки по требованию (вручную):

```
File -> Settings Repository -> Merge | Overwrite Local | Overwrite Remote
```

---

Однако по какой причине «через раз» синхронизируются `File Templates` и `Project Templates` я так и не выяснил.

Единственный 100%-ов рабочий способ — это написать Bash-скрипт, который коммитит папку `~/.PhpStorm<version>/config` на удалённый репозиторий, а на потом на нужной машине с помощью другого скрипта удалять текущую конфигурации PHPStorm и подсовывать новую.